# Sucessive quantifiers for same variable in disjoint sets.

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

The question is to determine whether the statement below is a valid translation of a English sentence, based on meaning of I(z, x), N(x) and *. I am not sure if using different quantifiers for the same variable is "legal", but when the sets C and F are disjoint surely it isn't even a well formed statement?

(∀x ∈ F) (∃x ∈ C) (∀z ∈ M) [I(z, x) ∧ N(z) =⇒ N(z ∗ x)]

Apologies if this is a stupid question, I have had no introduction to formal logic before, so I don't know what constitutes "legal" statements beyond intuition (which is dangerous to rely on).

Comment: It's not *ill-formed*, but quantifying a *sentence* with $x$ has no effect: there's no free $x$ for $\forall x\in F$ to bind. It's legal, but it's weird and probably doesn't say whatever you think it means. (And because it's weird in the way it is, I can't guess what you're trying to say.)

Comment: ohhh okay, what about using the same variable within a proposition that is already quantified, such as  (∀x)

PF x =⇒ (∃x) [PCx ∧ (∀z) [PMz ∧ I(z, x) ∧ N(z) =⇒ N(z ∗ x)]]
.
So does the fact that (∀x) is out front and  ∃x is in the middle also somewhat ruin an intended meaning?

Comment: No, that's clear: the scopes of the two $x$ quantifiers are disjoint. You'd only care about that if/when you wanted to move all quantifiers to the front (prenex normal form) — then you'd have to rename one. But have a care for the reader: if you use the same variable in two different places, they should be the same kind of thing. Why not just use $y$ instead of the second $x$, save us all a bit of trouble? :)